# How to draw smooth / rounded path?

Tags: java, android, path, paint

I am creating Paths and adding multi lines in each path by using `path.moveTo(x, y)` and `path.lineTo(x, y)`. Then `canvas.drawPath(path, paint)` is drawing all paths. But there are 1-2 pixel space between lines in some paths. How can I remove these spaces? My code is something like that:

```
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setDither(false);
paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     Path path = new Path();
     path.moveTo(a, b);
     path.lineTo(c, d);
     path.moveTo(c, d);
     path.lineTo(e, f);
     canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Comment: you need to put your code up.

Comment: Have you tried setting anti-aliasing on your Paint object?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Maybe this will create what you want

```
paint.setColor(color);                    // set the color
paint.setStrokeWidth(size);               // set the size
paint.setDither(true);                    // set the dither to true
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       // set to STOKE
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    // set the join to round you want
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);      // set the paint cap to round too
paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10) );   // set the path effect when they join.
paint.setAntiAlias(true);                         // set anti alias so it smooths
```

:)

Answer (score 12):

You probably don't want to `lineTo(c, d)` and then immediately `moveTo(c, d)` which is the same point. If you do this, you won't get a nice corner join on the two line segments, which may look like an ugly gap.

Try removing that `moveTo`.